# Advanced Search cannot clicked yii

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I have problem with my YII based application, in `controller/admin` there are link Advanced Search, if I click it must be show the form to search model. But when I click the link, nothing happened, I don't know why. I Also use `CJuiDatePicker` in my form. when I click the form, nothing happened too, it should be show calendar

I never change `controller/admin`, its generated by gii CRUD.
Anyone can help me :D

> I think all of my js or jquery or ajax is not working

Comment: And what does the console says ?

Comment: Any error or put some of your code?

Comment: what console do you mean?
no error displayed, my code is default from crud,i never change it

Comment: @Cesario your browser console. Use developer tools or firebug and note any errors.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).popover is not a function, that's the error.
And its like I failed load the JS extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, thanks to all
The problem is my js in Booster is missing accidentally, and I re-download again